# Git log: fatal object [sha1] is corrupted

Tags: git

Is there any way I can repair my repository with commit history in tact.

```
 # git log
fatal: object 01aeb2bf2e93b238f0e0422816b3e55518321ae7 is corrupted
```

From reading the link below it looks like I'll have zap it and start over.

http://www.miek.nl/s/7e76eadefe/

Comment: I should add that the root cause of this was disk corruption on my virtual machine, which wasn't shutting down correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have clones of this repository elsewhere? You might want to read [this post](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-17/src/git-htmldocs/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt) by Linus Torvalds to restore that corrupted object, assuming the corrupted object is a blob (file contents).

Comment: No clones. I just set this up yesterday. So I only had  10 commits.
I ended up starting fresh. But will definitely push it somewhere else at the end of every day. Lesson learned.

Still glad to be off svn. Git is fast!

Comment: Would be helpful to include the gist of the post in your answer, just incase, say, kernal.org ever gets hacked and is offline :(

Answer (score 8):

I wound up in the same situation, probably due to an improper shutdown of the virtual machine I was working in.  There were approximately 10 objects in .git/objects that had zero length. As far as I can tell, the actual source code files were fine, just the repository was hosed.

```
$ git status
fatal: object fbcf234634ee04f8406cfd250ce5ab8012f92b08 is corrupted
```

Per some suggestions I saw elsewhere (including Linus's post referenced above), I tried temporarily moving the corrupted objects git was complaining about from .git/objects elsewhere.  When had moved all of them, I got:

```
$ git status
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

After about an hour of Googling and trying various solutions, I gave up and started a new working copy using 'git clone' to pull from the origin (which was about 2 hours behind my working copy).  I then used `rsync -rC` (-C excludes SCM files) to copy the changed files from the messed-up working copy to my new working copy.

Comment: Same thing here VM corruption. rsync worked perfectly - nothing lost, just the log which was easy to recreate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to restore these objects by merely copying them from other repositories.

My virtual machine crashed while recording a pushed commit, so the objects were safely stored on a local computer. I scp'ed them to virtual machine and voila — git fsck outputs no errors.

Comment: it worked for me (git clone and copy/paste all my source code from broken folder to cloned folder).

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the corrupt object that git is complaining about.  I was able to resolve the same issue just now this way.

```
fatal: object 985a4870e7d890b314d2794377045a8b007c7925 is corrupted
```

For the above error, I was able to find corresponding object at:

```
project_directory/.git/objects/98/5a4870e7d890b314d2794377045a8b007c7925
```

Where you can see the file is 0 bytes and deleting it allowed the fetch to start working.

Presumably the previous fetch was interrupted, leaving the corrupt object with size = 0 bytes.

Comment: bizarre that this actually works, kind of like kicking the TV to clear up the static!

Comment: Didn't work for me and it sounds like a bad idea considering Torvalds' several page instruction on how to fix the corrupt object (listed above in the answer).

Comment: Didn't work for me neither. My object <hash> is nowhere to be found

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, whichever git command I ran, It ended up with the message:

```
fatal: object <hash> is corrupted
```

I didn't have a backup and didn't want to lose my commits, so I decided to try Jase's solution and removed the 0 length file I had : `.git/objects/00/<hash>`
Then got the same:

```
$ git status
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

Then, I tried to know what was wrong and looked into `.git/refs/heads/master`where I had the hash.

I looked into `.git/logs/refs/head/master`and found lines like this one:

```
<old commit> <new commit> <author> <timestamp> commit: <commit message>
```

I removed the last line (which had =) and pasted  of this line into `.git/refs/heads/master`, erasing its content

I was then able to commit successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I noticed that I wasn't logged in as root. When I logged in as root, I was able to check the log without the error sign.

To solidify this good status, I did this:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "stabilize git"
```

I exited out of root and tried pulling from a client.  It worked out for me afterwards.

When I did the add and commit, I knew that I was fine with what was in the directory. I had no changes visible through "git status".