# Getting fatal: object is corrupted when pushing to a remote repo

Tags: git, gitolite

I've got a server with Gitolite installed to host my repos I created a new repo yesterday and today when I tried to push more commits to the server I am getting:

```
fatal: object 86eeaa0c5a154ff3df34d6a43669930b9c6c7f59 is corrupted
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
error: failed to push some refs to
```

As the repo is pretty new I wasn't too bothered about losing previous commits so I have deleted both my local and remote repo but still getting the same error.

As I say I'm not too concerned about maintaing my commit history, I would just like to get it working again!

Comment: You did create your new repo by declaring it in the `gitolite.conf` file of a local clone of `gitolite-admin` repo, and pushing that `gitolite-admin` repo back to the gitolite server, right? (see http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/repos.html) You didn't `git init` directly yourself on the gitolite server, I presume?

Comment: And what version of gitolite do you have? Did you made some '`gl-xxx`' commands (like `gl-setup`)? Ie Gitolite V2. Or did you make a `gitolite install` (gitolite V3, or `g3`)

Comment: Yeah I declared the new repo in the `gitolite.conf` on my local machine and then pushed this back to the gitolite server, I then cloned that repo to my machine added the files, commited and pushed back to the server. This works fine, its only when I go to push to the server a 2nd time. I'm using version g3.

Comment: @VonC the over repo I have is working fine, I can clone and push commits to.

Comment: And the first repo (the one with the issue on the second push), can you clone it directly on the gitolite server (so local clone /path/to/repo) and see if you can push it back?

Comment: @VonC No I'm getting a `fatal: object 94b3887fa96f1a40e77f9a0cf9f566acb1e995a3 is corrupted` so I assume something is wrong with creating the new repo?

Comment: yes, if you can: try to redo the all creation process and see if that issue is repeatable. (add another repo in `gitolite.conf` and push again to `gitolite-admin`

Comment: @VonC Ok I didn't notice this before but when I create a new repo I'm getting the following error `remote: line 1 too long: command="/home/git/gitolite/src/gitolite...
remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for /tmp/Cdug9Itivq` But it's creating the repo in `/home/git/repositories`

Comment: So that needs to be resolved somehow. Can you try to create the ssh key as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736964/gitolite-admin-clone-issue/10738450#10738450 ? And use that one for cloning / pushing `gitolite-admin` repo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git log: fatal object \[sha1\] is corrupted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909225/git-log-fatal-object-sha1-is-corrupted)

Answer (score 5):

As seen in the comments, any additional repo has an issue during its creation (ie when pushing back the `gitolite-admin` repo with the `gitolite.conf` file declaring a new repo)

> I didn't notice this before but when I create a new repo I'm getting the following error:

```
remote: line 1 too long: command="/home/git/gitolite/src/gitolite... 
remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for /tmp/Cdug9Itivq
```

> But it's creating the repo in `/home/git/repositories`

This operation takes place in a post-compilation trigger called [**`ssh-authkeys`**](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/triggers/post-compile/ssh-authkeys):

```perl
sub fp_file {
    return $selinux++ if $selinux; # return a unique "fingerprint" to prevent noise
    my $f = shift;
    my $fp = `ssh-keygen -l -f '$f'`;
    chomp($fp);
    _die "fingerprinting failed for '$f'" unless $fp =~ /([0-9a-f][0-9a-f](:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])+)/;
    $fp = $1;
    return $fp;
}
```

That means `ssh-keygen -l -f <path_to_public_key.pub>` doesn't follow the right pattern, as shown in "[self service key management](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sskm.html)".

Make sure that your key is generated like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "${H}/.ssh/git" -C "Gitolite Admin access (not interactive)" -q -P ""
```

---

Update April 2015:

As mentioned by [starfry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712506/starfry) in "[Gitolite - remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for 'keydir/'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749581/6309)":

> There was a change to the key fingerprint format in OpenSSH at version 6.8:
>
> Add `FingerprintHash` option to `ssh(1)` and `sshd(8)`, and equivalent command-line flags to the other tools to control algorithm used for key fingerprints. The default changes from MD5 to SHA256 and format from hex to base64.
>
> Fingerprints now have the hash algorithm prepended.
>   An example of the new format:

```
SHA256:mVPwvezndPv/ARoIadVY98vAC0g+P/5633yTC4d/wXE
```

> Please note that visual host keys will also be different.
>
> The [latest git checkout of gitolite is aware](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/ed807a40c6683960e357bc995b3acf721ec088b4), since 18th March '15, of this new format.

Comment: Thanks for another very informative answer! I've generated a new key as suggested. What do I need to do with the `git.pub` key now?

Comment: @simon: use that key as described in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/setup.html (so with an id.pub renamed into a 'generic account name' dedicated for gitolite ssh administration: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736964/gitolite-admin-clone-issue/10738450#10738450 for illustration), in order to initiate again the `gitolite-admin` repo, clone it, declare new repos, clone them and see if the issue persists.

Comment: The fingerprint version changed with OpensSSH 6.8 See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29749581)

Comment: @starfry I see. I have included your answer here as well, for more visibility.