# gitolite-admin clone issue

Tags: git, ubuntu, clone, gitolite

I am going nuts with a problem cloning the gitolite-admin repository.
I have followed this http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html#migr and it went perfectly.

I ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub morten@ubuntu-server:/tmp/morten.pub`

authorized_keys on the server looks like this:

```
# gitolite start
command="/home/morten/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell morten",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forward$
# gitolite end
```

Which AFAIK is okay.

When I run `git clone morten@ubuntu-server:gitolite-admin` on my client, I get

```
fatal: 'gitolite-admin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have no idea what I missed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `morten` account is perfectly fine.

However, your installation is strange, considering your current `~morten/.ssh/authorized_keys` content:

Instead of `/home/morten/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell morten`|, you should have `/home/morten/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell morten`

That means: `gitolite-shell` should be in your `$PATH`, and it should be in a bin directory, created after executing:

```
"${github}/install" -to "${gtl}/bin"
```

(See option 3 of the "actual install" section of "[**Installing Gitolite**](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html)")

with:

- `github` the path where you have cloned  `https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite`
- `gtl` the path where you want to install gitolite (in your case, for instance, `/home/morten/gitolite`)

Then, it is easier to save your `authorized_keys` and `.gitolite.rc` file, and re-do the initialization process:

```
gitolite setup -pk "${HOME}/.ssh/gitoliteadm.pub"
```

(provided you created your public and private key, naming it '`gitoliteadm`', with a simple:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "${H}/.ssh/morten" -C "Gitolite Admin access (not interactive)" -q -P ""
```

)

Note that I keep the 'ssh' account name (`morten`) different than the gitolite server account (`gitoliteadm`) on purpose.

You will still clone with `git clone morten@ubuntu-server:gitolite-admin` (because all ssh files are in `~morten/.ssh`), but you will do so with the private/public key of `gitoliteadm`, prompting gitolite to access its repo with a gitolite "account" named "`gitoliteadm`".

That way, if you change physical user account for your gitolite server, the "logical" account '`gitoliteadm`' (referring to a *role*, not to a person or resource).

Comment: Thank you very much! Followed these steps and it seems to be working now :)

To start from scratch I did a complete reinstall of the ubuntu-server (it was almost a fresh install anyway) and changed the username to "ubuntu" to avoid any confusion - and now when I do:

git clone ubuntu@ubuntu-server:gitolite-admin

it makes a clone to my client - so that tells me it is working as it should!

Thanks again!

Comment: I have one more question I hope you can help with:

When I do a: git push -u origin master
I get: FATAL: W any ubuntu/crm gitoliteadm DENIED by fallthru

Comment: @MortenHagh what is your remote? (`git remote -v` in your local repo)

Comment: git remote -v give me:
crm ubuntu@ubuntu-server:crm (fetch) /
crm ubuntu@ubuntu-server:crm (push)

Comment: @MortenHagh so you don't have a remote named '`origin`'?

Comment: @Morten sound fine, but then, you should `git push -u crm master` then.

Comment: I think I made it work :) I can push now with git origin master (started over) and it pushes absolutely fine! :)

Sorry for asking this much, but I'm in the learning process! :)

Thanks again!

Comment: I am getting the same issue regarding gitolite installation instructions followed on http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite any idea why running `gitolite/install -ln` would cause the /src/gitolite-shell to appear in the authorized_keys?

Comment: @thenaglecode not sure: I always install `gitolite` with `"${github}/install" -to "${gtl}/bin"`, never using `ln`.