# gitlab 5.2 can clone and push by http, but can't clone or push by ssh

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have setup my gitlab server behind a route, and I have mapped my ssh port to 50000 in the server. the gitlab port is 50001.Then I create a test project and try to clone it in another machine,it's ok when I use http.

```
git remote add origin http://myrouteaddress:50001/user/test.git
```

but when I try to test it use ssh, it failed with

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@myrouteaddress:50000/user/test.git

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have test my ssh setting with

```
ssh -vT git@myrouteaddress -p 50000
```

and it passed without problem.

I find out the auth with

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

and get the follow

```
Jun  1 12:29:22 debian sshd[24799]: Accepted publickey for git from mytestpcip port 37848 ssh2
Jun  1 12:29:22 debian sshd[24799]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
Jun  1 12:29:22 debian sshd[24801]: Received disconnect from mytestpcip: 11: disconnected by user
Jun  1 12:29:22 debian sshd[24799]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user git
```

can someone tell me the reason? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the reason, I have generate the ssh rsa key with wrong parameter. the right way is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@email.com"
```

Comment: Excellent (that complements my own answer below), just like I like to create my ssh keys, as, for instance, in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16154236/6309 +1

Answer (score 0):

Check your config:

```
# check gitlab-shell install
sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check

# check gitlab install
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

Then, try and use the scp syntax:

```
git@myrouteaddress:50000:user/test.git
or
gitolite:user/test.git
```

With a [config file in your `~/.ssh/config`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922461/6309) with

```
Host gitolite
   Hostname myrootaddress # or ip address
   Port 5000 
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git
```

Comment: I have checked my config file, it passed all with green or OK.I have already write my `~/.ssh/config` file with hostname and port.I found I can's ssh to the remote host now.


    ssh myrouteaddress -p 50000 -l git
    PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
    Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
    Connection to myrouteaddress closed.

Comment: @yeluolei so `ssh -Tv gitolite:user/test.git` doesn't work when your ~/.ssh/config is properly set?