# How to fix URL given after creating a new repo's in gitlab?

Tags: configuration, ssh, gitlab

When creating a new project, on the final step gitlab give me instructions to setup my repo, but the URL to the repo don't work. For instance, to add remote branch, I got:

```
git remote add origin git@git.srv.com:root/home.git
```

`Note:` My gitlab instance is running on a virtual machine whom host forward SSH's requests on port `1122` to the VM's port `22`. So locally gitlab is reach on port `22`.

### Given URL doesn't work

#### Pushing

Keep asking for password. Neither my SSH passphrase nor my account's password works:

```
git push -u manu master                                        
Password: 
Password: 
Password: 
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

## Cloning

Same here, keep prompting for password:

```
git clone git@git.srv.com:1122/root/home.git      
Cloning into 'home'...
Password:
```

### Fixing the URL (add protocol and port)

If I simply add a `ssh://` prefix and the port to the server (`:1122/`) everything work smoothly:

```
git remote add manu ssh://git@git.srv.com:1122/root/home.git
```

Answer (score 0):

The surest way to debug this kind of ssh access is to launch an `sshd -d` session on the server and see the output (it is a one-time debug connection).

Note that `git@git.srv.com:root/home.git` is an url using an [scp syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php), which means you have [a `~/.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870267/6309), with an entry named `git.srv.com`, which can reference your private key (`IdentityFile`), as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870267/6309) for instance.
You can also check its content to see if it does contain the right value (including the right Port)

Comment: The SSH works fine, but gitlab interface doesn't display the port `1122` so URL given are incorrectly build. I don't get any `~/.ssh/config` file in my `/home/git` directory, I will check that.

Comment: @EdouardLopez I confirm that if you don't have a `~/.ssh/config` **on the client side** (*not* on the server `git` account, but on the machine where you try to ssh your way to the gitlab server), a syntax like `xxx:yyy` (with a '`:`') won't work.

Comment: I'm looking for a server-side solution

Comment: @EdouardLopez but your git clone command is done on the client side, right? Hence my previous comment.

Comment: Yep, but I a server-side solution will be a lot more sure

Comment: @EdouardLopez either way, an scp syntax means you have to have a `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Understood that and thanks for the knowledge, but that's not my initial question.