# ssh connection to git failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitlab

I am opening some question I somewhat asked before but now the problem seems to be pretty linked to `ssh`.

1. I have installed Gitlab in `/home/myuser/gitlab`.
2. I created a rep `test`
3. Following instructions, I added a remote `git@localhost:root/testing.git` (`Gitlab`'s server runs on port 3000)

Now, when I try to push, I get this error message:

```
$ git push -u origin master
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname mylocalhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now, I found that there was a problem with my ssh connect. Here's my `/home/myhome/.ssh/config` file

```
Host mylocalhost
Hostname localhost
PORT 3000
User git
IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

When I run `ssh mylocalhost` I get this message

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On verbose mode, it seems that the connection is established on the right port but the porcess fails here `debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`. 
I tried to update my `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` (I am using `OSX`) to forward port listening to `3000` but then the `Gitlab` `Webrick` `Rails` server won't run anymore. L tried to change `git remote set-url origin mylocalhost:testing.git`

Comment: possible duplicate of [git remote add with other ssh port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596260/git-remote-add-with-other-ssh-port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I figured out what was the problem. I had to set properly the `~/.ssh/config` file

```
 Host mylocalhost
    Hostname localhost
//I deleted a line specifying the PORT to 3000
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa //It was previously set to /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then I reinstalled a key but I still got some problem. Finally, setting the perm of the file `/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa` to 644 and it worked just fine. For information, I found searching in the web that some settings could work with a `700` or a `600` chmod perm, but for me `644` did the trick

Comment: Sounds good. I have written before about permissions for ssh files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3712619/6309

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab's HTTP interface is probably running on port 3000, but SSH isn't running there to push the repository to.

The message of `ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused` means that the SSH client was unable to connect to the SSH server at `localhost` on port 22. I'd ensure you've [installed gitlab correctly](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) and Gitlab is running correctly. Also ensuring the ssh server is running and able to accept connections on port 22.

Comment: oh so sorry, I have updated my post, the error message is now not the same

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hope to use the port 3000 if you are using a fully specified url

```
 git@localhost:root/testing.git
```

As [I have explained to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729185/ssh-connection-failing-when-pushing-on-a-gitlab-repo/17730283#comment25846186_17730283):

> The idea of the ssh config file is to define an entry "`foobar`" which will set the right server name (`Hostname`), ssh private key (`IdentityFile`), and user under which the ssh session is opened.
>   That would allow to do '`ssh foobar`' (**without having to put `git@xxx`**, and with non-standard public/private keys files).
>   You can define as many entry as you want, allowing you to use different user and keys.

So you cannot define origin with `git@xxx`. You must type:

```
git remote add origin mylocalhost:testing.git
```

Or, if origin is already defined, and you need to change its url:

```
git remote set-url origin mylocalhost:testing.git
```

(no '`root/`' you don't specify any path in front of a gitlab repo: gitlab will deduce the full path of the repo)

But you need to be *sure* your sshd starts on port 3000, and that `gitlab.yml` contains that port number.

---

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mylocalhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

That means ssh cannot find `~/.ssh/config`, with a `mylocalhost` entry in it.
Make sure that file exist.

Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17729185/6309) put in  `~/.git/config`, which has nothing to do with ssh.

Comment: sorry, I had a copy paste pb, the error message is no longer the same.  In fact,  when I change the `sshd` port as explained here: http://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x, my `Webrick` `Rails` server won't no longer run ...

Comment: Sure I have it (I also verufy `sudo` user can see it). Here's how it is Host mylocalhost
Hostname localhost
PORT 3000
User git
IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` Btw, when I launch `ssh -v mylocalhost`, the connection is established with the right `HOSTNAME` and in the right `PORT`

Comment: @Newben What `git remote -v` returns within the repo you are trying to push to origin? And on the gitlab side, does a `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` complete successfully?

Comment: the result of the first request is 'origin mylocalhost:testing.git (fetch)
origin mylocalhost:testing.git (push)' and the  second completes successfully

Comment: in fact, I have `.ssh` `config` file is in `/home/myhome/`, but `GitLab` is running under `/home/myuser`. Should I add a `.ssh` `config` file under `/home/myuser` ?

Comment: @Newben gitlab should be running in the exact account proposed by the **[setup documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/installation.md): `git`. Your ssh config is for your client account to use, and has nothing to do with the account running gitlab. It is a convenient way to use a "simpler" ssh url `mylocalhost:testing.git` instead of `git@yourserver:3000/testing.git`.

Comment: Ok, things are changing now I deleted the `PORT 3000` line in my `.ssh/config` and now `ssh mylocalhost` works just well. But when I run `git push -u origin master` I am said that `fatal: 'testing.git' does not appear to be a git repository` I thing only `sudo` can see the repo. But when I run `sudo git push -u origin master`, I get `ssh: Could not resolve hostname mylocalhost`. In fact, `sudo ssh mylocalhost` fails, because it doesn't seem to fetch data from `ssh` `config` file. Should I add config lines into `/opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config` ?

Comment: @Newben I confirm a `sudo git push` could not possibly work: you clone, push pull as *a client*: `yourhome`. Not as `root` (again, forget `root`, you only need `sudo` in the gitlab setup). `sudo` will execute command as `root`, which has not an ssh config file like your account (and shouldn't have).

Comment: In fact, I notice that `ssh mylocalhost` connects me to `/home/myuser`, and not in `/home/myuser/gitlab`. But `git remote set-url origin mylocalhost:gitlab/testing.git` won't change the output of `git push -u origin master` fatal: 'gitlab/other.git' does not appear to be a git repository. Btw, it seems I should add again `PORT 3000` in my ssh config file, but then I still get `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` when I push. What a mess !;) So when you said `make sure your sshd starts on port 3000`, how to do it on `osx` ? I tried a lot of things, but none worked

Comment: @Newben I agree. At this point, try to simply redo the all setup process, following *exactly* the convention (in term of accounts) proposed in it. No need for port 3000.