# symlink issue when pushing on gitlab

Tags: git, push, symlink, gitlab

I have some issue when pushing on a `gitlab project repo`. When I run `git push -u origin master` to let's say a remote repo `/Users/home/repositories/root/other.git`, I get this output :

```
remote: hooks/update:10: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

I think it may come from symlinking issue. Because, I have `update` and `post-receive` files inside `/Users/home/repositories/root/other.git`, and when I delete them and symlink to `/Users/home/gitlab-shell/hooks/update` and `/Users/home/gitlab-shell/hooks/post-receive`, and when I run again push, I have the same error and `update` and `post-receive` files appear again under `/Users/home/repositories/root/other.git`. Could someone help ?

Comment: What git version are you using? Are you pushing directly on the GitLab server? (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3349#issuecomment-15386092)

Comment: @VonC, no I am using it on my local. If I run `ruby -v`, I get `ruby 2.0.0` !

Comment: And what gitlab version have you installed on your server?

Comment: @VonC this is the branch `5-0-stable`

Comment: That seem old... and not compatible with ruby 2.0. Only 6.x would support ruby 2.0

Comment: @VonC I have updated my branch. Now when I run `git push -u origin master`, I get `/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)` and of course when I sudo, my `.ssh/config` file is no  longer taken into account. How can i manage this perm issue ?

Comment: You can start by following the questions / recommendations of https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4566.

Comment: @VonC thank you and I followed it. But I setup correctly `gitlab_urb` tp `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` and I still get this `connection refused` error. Should I set up `Redis`

Comment: So `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` and `sudo -u git -H ./home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check` both return an ok status?

Comment: I confirm redis shoud run (like https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5270#issuecomment-25741479 illustrates)

Comment: Not sure about that '0.0.0.0' ip address though. Your server is on the same machine than your client?

Comment: @VonC I confirm redis is running (but no config setup in `gitlab-shell` ). Btw, I get some errors : I checkout `gitlab-shell` to `v1.7.1` branch tag, but I still get this message `FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to 1.7.1 from 1.1.0`

Comment: Strange: Would https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake#L738-L767 be buggy (as it was 7 month ago? (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3404). But for http url, I don't know how the Redis server would interpret a 0.0.0.0 ip address.

Comment: @VonC but yesterday everything was working just fine, with the same configuration (I had `gitlab 5`)

Comment: Check the config (`config/gitlab.yml`): it has changed/evolved between 5 and 6.

Comment: @VonC Ok I am going to do that. Just to be sure as for the gitlab-shell tag. I created a branch called `v1.7.1` and did some `git pull origin v1.7.1`. Is it Ok ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a branch. A simple `git pull` in `gitlab-shell` submodule should have been enough to bring you the latest.

Comment: I confirm ;) https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/VERSION should show 1.7.1. Simply try to reset your `HEAD` in `gitlab-shell` to the latest: `git fetch ; git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @VonC now it works ;) So The error I get when running `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` is `.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:603:in `initialize': Permission denied`. Btw, my gitlab config seems correct

Comment: Do you mean that everything now works? That you still have an error on the `gitlab:check`, but GitLab itself is still working despite that check error?

Comment: @VonC I still get the same error when I run `git push -u origin master` : `.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:603:in initialize: Permission denied`

Comment: I have only see this at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3951#issuecomment-17923525, but without resolution. That might be useful to present your case on the GitLab forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gitlabhq).

Comment: @VonC I did it ! Btw, how to configure my `.ssh/config` as a sudo. It will be perhaps simpler !

Comment: By sudo, do you means as root? or as your GitLab account (like 'git')? My GitLab `ssh/config` file looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/16870267/6309.

Comment: @VonC I mean as root in order not to have perm issue. When I run `sudo git push -u origin master`; I get `ssh: Could not resolve hostname mylocalhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: That means first that your `ssh/config` is wrong. What is the url of your remote repo your are pushing to? An ssh one?

Comment: Yes I try to push from `/home/git/gitlab/somerepo` to `/home/git/gitlab/repositories/root/somerepo` with an `/home/git/.ssh/config` as so `Host mylocalhost
Hostname localhost
User git
IdentityFile /Users/git/.ssh/id_rsa` and the same exact config parameter inside `/home/myhome/.ssh/config`

Comment: And what is the ssh url? Plus you only need that config file on the client side (ie in the homedir of the '`myhome`' account). Not on the server side (`/home/git`). You are pushing as 'myhome', right? Not as git or root.

Comment: @VonC I thought it was `/home/git/gitlab/repositories/root/somerepo`. If not where can I find it ? Yes I am pushing as `myhome`

Comment: What `git remote -v` returns when types within your cloned repo in /home/myhome?

Comment: @VonC I get `origin mylocalhost:root/other.git (fetch)
origin mylocalhost:root/other.git (push)`

Comment: Then yes, it should be at `/home/git/gitlab/repositories/root/other.git`. Again, the forum might be more useful here. Nothing should be owned by `root` though. Everything should be owned by `git`.

Comment: @VonC Thank yo for all. Just for curiosity, how the request is processed by `gitlab` when I run `git push` ?

Comment: The `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` will call `gitlab-shell` first to check if you are authorized. Then GitLab calls git.

Comment: @VonC I come back again with some news : I chomed to 777 some log file, that for some reason didn't have the right perms. But now, I go back to the same error I experienced yesterday with the `5.0` `gitlab` version ! Here's the result of `git push -u master` : `remote: hooks/update:11: undefined method require_relative for main:Object (NoMethodError)
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To mylocalhost:root/other.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to mylocalhost:root/other.git`

Comment: @VonC in fact when I add `puts RUBY_VERSION` `~/repositories/test.git/hooks/update`, I get `remote: 1.8.7`, how can it be ?

Comment: Because https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/hooks/update uses `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` and the `$PATH` in the account used for GitLab must be different than the one used for your account: one must reference the ruby installed in `/usr/bin` I presume.

Comment: @VonC ok thank you ! So how can i change this reference ?