# Gitolite - remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for 'keydir/'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitolite

I installed Gitolite in my system to manage the repositories. When i try to add any of the client machine's public key, am getting the error "remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for 'keydir/". Would you please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I documented in "[Getting fatal: object is corrupted when pushing to a remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744027/6309)", this is due to an incorrect ssh key.

I like to generate my private/public keys like so (not password protected):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "$HOME/.ssh/git" -C "Gitolite access (not interactive)" -q -P ""
```

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this problem while working on a new install. There was a change to the key fingerprint format in OpenSSH at version 6.8:

> Add FingerprintHash option to ssh(1) and sshd(8), and equivalent
>      command-line flags to the other tools to control algorithm used
>      for key fingerprints. The default changes from MD5 to SHA256 and
>      format from hex to base64.
>
> Fingerprints now have the hash algorithm prepended. An example of
>      the new format: SHA256:mVPwvezndPv/ARoIadVY98vAC0g+P/5633yTC4d/wXE
>      Please note that visual host keys will also be different.

The latest git checkout of gitolite [is aware](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/ed807a40c6683960e357bc995b3acf721ec088b4), since 18th March '15, of this new format.

Answer (score 1):

This message can also be seen after adding SSH2 (Putty) key to gitolite.
In that is the case a simple conversion from SSH2 to OpenSSH key can be done this way:

```sh
ssh-keygen -i -f ssh2.pub > openssh.pub
```