# Can not add user with Gitolite (centos)

Tags: git, gitolite

I am newby with gitolite. I've install gitolite on a remote server(192.168.1.109)

So I could git-cloning gitolite-admin.git.

```
git clone ssh://git@192.168.1.109/gitolite-admin.git
```

wanted to add user and repo using gitolite. following is ordinary add user process.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "test" -f test
```

added the public key in `keydir/test.pub`

and then, `git add` / `git commit` / `git push` is done well, GitServer echo msg for git push is:

```
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: keydir/test.pub: Permission denied
remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for 'keydir/test.pub'
To ssh://git@192.168.1.109/gitolite-admin.git
5b8c75d..8c12dac  master -> master
```

My remote server is CentOS.

```
remote: keydir/test.pub: Permission denied
remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for 'keydir/test.pub'
```

How would you avoid that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have generated a `test.pub` key, you should use a `test` user in your gitolite.conf.

Try again, as I mention in:

- "[gitolite setup getting FATAL: fingerprinting failed for '/tmp/Q3pnE4WVbu'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154236/6309)"
- "[Gitolite - remote: FATAL: fingerprinting failed for 'keydir/'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17301477/6309)"

> `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "${H}/.ssh/test" -C "Gitolite Admin access (not interactive)" -q -P ""`

As illustrated in [this blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/hesco/2014/03/resolving-gitolites-remote-fatal-fingerprinting-failed-for-keydirsome-userpub.html):

> Digging about in the gitolite code reveals this error is thrown when a regex fails to find a valid looking fingerprint after running `ssh-keygen -l -f 'path/to/key.pub'`. (See [`man ssh-keygen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) for details).
>
> To resolve the issue, run that command locally and have it generate a valid fingerprint before you push your configuration changes to the gitolite server. I found my issue was that I had failed to include the '`ssh-rsa` ' prefix to the key.