# gitolite-admin trigger POST_COMPILE failed

Tags: git, gitolite

I tried to add another user to my gitolite config. This is what I see in logs:

```
    2015-06-30.23:12:12     10361   pre_git gitolite-admin  marcin  W       any     refs/.*
    2015-06-30.23:12:12     10361           system,git,shell,-c,git-receive-pack '/share/Projects/githome/repositories/gitolite-admin.git'
    2015-06-30.23:12:15     10361   update  gitolite-admin  marcin  W       refs/heads/master       6c3c809a3656ed37097605562ac43cfd87d251ea        1d02b5874b46463c86831fefad4225bf6b5e7f47        refs/.*
    2015-06-30.23:12:17     10361           system,gitolite compile
    2015-06-30.23:12:21     10361           system,gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE
    2015-06-30.23:12:23     10361           system,/share/HDA_DATA/Projects/githome/gitolite/src/triggers/post-compile/ssh-authkeys,POST_COMPILE
    2015-06-30.23:12:26     10361   die     fingerprinting failed for '/tmp/0j7vu4KyoE'
    2015-06-30.23:12:26     10361           system() failed,/share/HDA_DATA/Projects/githome/gitolite/src/triggers/post-compile/ssh-authkeys,POST_COMPILE,-> 6400
    2015-06-30.23:12:26     10361           system() failed,gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE,-> 6400
    2
```

I was modyfying this repo several times, it works for two years with no problem. 
How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/25562187/6309 help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/10744027/6309?

Comment: not really, will describe it in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed src/triggers/post-compile/ssh-authkeys gitolite perls script and found out that ssh-keygen -l -f $f is returning an error.
The keys were ok, but the script is generating temporary files containing lines from authorized_keys file. Those files were empty because there was no space left on the device :)